# Looking for a manga/WEBTOON, specifically isekai

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

What I remember of the plot is this:

The MC is a boy, not very old, who got transported to another world to fight demon lords. You’re introduced to a couple heros that fight with MC, they’re all on the cover. You’re made to believe this is just a run of the mill hero manga. However, when MC goes to fight the demon lord, he is easily defeated, and the cycle starts again. All the heroes he has been fighting alongside are dead as well. There’s some sort of system where heroes register to fight demon lords, and there are a lot of them. It uses a level system of some sort to classify the demon lords; the world the MC has been transported to is plagued by them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Does the MC survive this fight, or does the next cycle use a different main character? About what chapter does the demon lord fight take place; 1? 5? 40?